# Unparsable Date exception?

Tags: java, android

I would appreciate any help with finding bug for this exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-11-28-12:53 PM"
```

and following code :

```
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm a");

String TimeStamp = adptAllTests.get(i).getDateString()+""+adptAllTests.get(i).getStartTime();
Long startTimeStamp = format.parse(TimeStamp).getTime();
```

it throws an exception while parsing `TimeStamp` to `startTimeStamp`

Comment: what does `HH` mean? Would you use it with `a` ?

Comment: for time..actually i want to convert "2017-11-28-12:53 PM"  this format into long

Comment: Please [check the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) before posting next time.

Comment: I guess my hints were too subtle

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't alter the code you originally posted to fix it. Otherwise, the question will be no longer valid.

Comment: ok..thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong format:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm a");
```

It should be:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm a");
```

**h** represents    Hour in am/pm (1-12)

**H**   represents Hour in day (0-23)

In your case i think you forgot to add a "-" between date and time . change the following line as below.

```
String TimeStamp = adptAllTests.get(i).getDateString()+"-"+adptAllTests.get(i).getStartTime();
```

Comment: Actually i was using this  'SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm a");' for parsing ... i wrote HH by mistek while posting...and that is not working for

Comment: You are missing an "-" between date and time see my updated answer. And let me know if its solved your problem.

Comment: Its working with the date you posted in question i have tested it myself .Print your String TimeStamp before parsing it and check if its formated or not.